# Magento 2 : Store Email Address

Tags: magento2, checkout, customer, email

Is there a way to have **customers email address** automatically recorded at the **back end** after they enter it on **checkout page** but they do not place order?

I want to have a **record of customers** who leave the site before they submit the quote request so I can contact them for follow up.

Comment: You can use newsletter popup compulsory for all unique user to make this functionality.

Comment: you can do this using custom extension at checkout.

Answer (score 0):

You can get `customer_email` column from `quote` table where `reserved_order_id` is empty

Database Query:

```
SELECT q.customer_email FROM quote q
WHERE q.reserved_order_id IS NULL
GROUP BY q.customer_email
```